# Priority of properties in Laplace Transform.

Tags: laplace-transform

Supose I have a function f(t) which corresponding Laplace Transform is F(s)

Now I want to calculate the Laplace transform of $f(a (t-b))$ using Laplace Transform properties.

If $L(g(t))= G(s)$

Property A: Time shift $L( g(t-a)) = e^{-a s} G(s)$

Property B. Time scaling $L(g(at) = \frac{1}{a} G(\frac{s}{a}) )$

Then I have a question about the order in which I can use them.

For example if I go A then B:

$L(g(a(t-b))) = e^{-b s} L(g(at))$

$e^{-b s} L(g(at)) = e^{-b s} L( g(t-a)) = e^{-b s} \frac{1}{a} G(\frac{s}{a}) $

If I go B then A:

$L(g(a(t-b))) = \frac{1}{a} L( g(t-b) ) $ the transform must be evaluated with $\frac{s}{a}$

$\frac{1}{a} L( g(t-b) ) = \frac{1}{a} e^{-bs} L( g(t) ) = \frac{1}{a} e^{-b \frac{s}{a}} G(\frac{s}{a}) $

Which one is correct?

Please correct me if anything is wrong, even language :D (not native here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second one
$$L(g(a(t-b))) =L(g(at-ab))) = \frac{1}{a} L( g(t-ab) )$$
 the transform must be evaluated with $s/a$
$$L(g(a(t-b))) = \frac{1}{a} e^{-abs/a}G(\frac s a)$$
$$L(g(a(t-b))) = \frac{1}{a} e^{-bs}G(\frac s a)$$
It gives the same answer in both cases.